# How to pass a select menu in ransack gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ransack

I am trying to implement a search field with a dropdown select menu with options for category field using ransack gem.
this is what I am trying to acheive

```
<%= f.select :category, ["",  "Art", "Books and Movies", "Clothing","Collectibles", "Computers & Related", "Construction Materials", "Crafts & Hobbies", "Entertainment" %>
```

but I don't know how to do it using ransack

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing a closing bracket:

```
<%= f.select :category, ["",  "Art", "Books and Movies", "Clothing","Collectibles", "Computers & Related", "Construction Materials", "Crafts & Hobbies", "Entertainment"] %>
```

That should work, I just tested something similar.

You could also do something like:

```
<%= f.select :category, Category.all.collect{|c| [u.name, u.name]} %>
```

Assuming you have a category model.